# No Inicia el Job Scheduler de Pentaho Community Version 8.0.0-28

Tags: pentaho

Estoy intentando automatizar la ejecución de una transformación, pero no se ejecuta.

¿Puede ser una limitacion del Pentaho Data Integration Community?

La fuente de la transformación, la traigo de un equipo remoto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto imagen para que vean como lo estoy Scheduleando.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puede ser que el problema sea que el archivo lo traiga de un equipo remoto y por eso el Schedule falla?

Probe tambien de armar un archivo.bat para que se ejecute con una tarea de windows

```
    cd "C:\PCE\data-integration" >  
   C:\PCE\Scripts\logOOF.txt
```

pan.bat 
         /file:C:\PCE\Transformaciones\Resumen.ktr

> > C:\PCE\Scripts\logOOF.txt
> >              exit

y me da el siguiente error:

```
DEBUG: Using JAVA_HOME
DEBUG: _PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_161
DEBUG: _PENTAHO_JAVA=C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_161\bin\java.exe

C:\PCE\data-integration>"C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_161\bin\java.exe"  "-Xms1024m" "-Xmx2048m" "-XX:MaxPermSize=256m" "-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2" "-Djava.library.path=libswt\win64" "-DKETTLE_HOME=" "-DKETTLE_REPOSITORY=" "-DKETTLE_USER=" "-DKETTLE_PASSWORD=" "-DKETTLE_PLUGIN_PACKAGES=" "-DKETTLE_LOG_SIZE_LIMIT=" "-DKETTLE_JNDI_ROOT=" -jar launcher\pentaho-application-launcher-8.0.0.0-28.jar -lib ..\libswt\win64  -main org.pentaho.di.pan.Pan -initialDir "C:\PCE\data-integration"\ /file:C:\PCE\Transformaciones\Resumen.ktr 
08:32:03,175 INFO  [KarafBoot] Checking to see if org.pentaho.clean.karaf.cache is enabled
08:32:04,347 ERROR [ServerSocketBasedKarafInstanceResolver] Error creating ServerSocket
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.pentaho.platform.osgi.ServerSocketBasedKarafInstanceResolver.resolveInstanceNumber(ServerSocketBasedKarafInstanceResolver.java:207)
    at org.pentaho.platform.osgi.ServerSocketBasedKarafInstanceResolver.resolveInstance(ServerSocketBasedKarafInstanceResolver.java:65)
    at org.pentaho.platform.osgi.KarafInstance.assignPortsAndCreateCache(KarafInstance.java:152)
    at org.pentaho.platform.osgi.KarafBoot.createAndProcessKarafInstance(KarafBoot.java:329)
    at org.pentaho.platform.osgi.KarafBoot.startup(KarafBoot.java:224)
    at org.pentaho.di.osgi.registryExtension.OSGIPluginRegistryExtension.init(OSGIPluginRegistryExtension.java:109)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.plugins.PluginRegistry.init(PluginRegistry.java:596)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.KettleClientEnvironment.init(KettleClientEnvironment.java:115)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.KettleClientEnvironment.init(KettleClientEnvironment.java:79)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.KettleEnvironment.init(KettleEnvironment.java:124)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.KettleEnvironment.init(KettleEnvironment.java:98)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.KettleEnvironment.init(KettleEnvironment.java:79)
    at org.pentaho.di.pan.Pan.main(Pan.java:73)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.pentaho.commons.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:92)
08:32:08,378 INFO  [KarafInstance] 
*******************************************************************************
*** Karaf Instance Number: 2 at C:\PCE\data-integration\.\system\karaf\cach ***
***   es\pan\data-1                                                         ***
*** FastBin Provider Port:52902                                             ***
*** Karaf Port:8803                                                         ***
*** OSGI Service Port:9052                                                  ***
*******************************************************************************
2018/04/10 08:32:20 - Pan - Start of run.
2018/04/10 08:32:21 - Resumen - Dispatching started for transformation [ResumenMagma]
2018/04/10 08:32:21 - Table output.0 - Connected to database [Conexion 10.120.50.10] (commit=1000)
2018/04/10 08:32:22 - Archivo Magma.0 - Finished processing (I=0, O=0, R=0, W=0, U=0, E=1)
2018/04/10 08:32:22 - Resumen - Transformation detected one or more steps with errors.
2018/04/10 08:32:22 - Resumen - Transformation is killing the other steps!
2018/04/10 08:32:22 - Pan - Finished!
2018/04/10 08:32:22 - Pan - Start=2018/04/10 08:32:20.920, Stop=2018/04/10 08:32:22.229
2018/04/10 08:32:22 - Pan - Processing ended after 1 seconds.
```

Answer (score 0):

Por si les pasa todo lo descripto mas arriba les paso lo que tuve que modificar para que todo funcionara ok.

El error mas arriba especificado, se debia a que algun aplicativo estaba ocupando el mismo puerto que Pentaho. Tuve que reiniciar el Server y se soluciono.

Luego me encontre que creando una tarea de windows no ejecutara el archivo.bat que habia armado para la ejecución de la transformación.

Esto se debía a que lo archivos al estar en un repositorio remoto y con todos los permisos para el usuario que ejecuta, no funcionaba.

De esta forma, primero debía crear un archivo.bat que copiara los archivos remotos en alguna carpeta local y por último modificar el bat original donde ejecutaba la trasnformacion de Pentaho.

De esta forma Funciono correctamente.

No hubo forma para que funcionara el job scheduler de Pentaho y desconozco todavía porque no ejecuta.

Espero pueda ayudarlos con estos tips.

Saludos,
Oscar.

Comment: Si esto resuelve el problema, mejora la respuesta siguiendo [answer]. Un saludo